# How to force import a lib from python site-package?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using custom django struct as below: 
all settings file in `conf`, all app in `src`
[image]

and  need use below manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    SRC_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'src')
    CONF_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'conf')
    sys.path.insert(0, SRC_PATH)
    sys.path.insert(0, CONF_PATH)

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And I also need to use celery in django.

But django-celery need a `celery.py` file in same directory with `settings.py`.

When `runserver` ,it would raise `ImportError: cannot import name Celery` because below code:

```
sys.path.insert(0, SRC_PATH)
sys.path.insert(0, CONF_PATH)
```

It import itself! not from site-package, because `CONF_PATH` is before `site-package`.

But I can't change that to

```
sys.path.append(SRC_PATH)
sys.path.append(CONF_PATH)
```

This way would cause `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

For now, the only way I know is changing `celery.py` to `celery_somename.py`, and I have to type this name every time when I start a celery job.

How do I force import a lib from python site-package? Or is there another way to start celery?

Comment: The wise solution would be to amend your "custom django struct" so that you don't have to mess with `sys.path` at all...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers my `custom django struct` is more suitable for deployment.It could reduce the complexity of deployment, and that is also my company's decision.I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add at the top of the `celery.py` module and other modules importing celery:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

This will make imports absolute by default, now:

```
import celery
```

Will import the installed celery package and not this module.

Comment: This code is in celery doc too, but it does not work.

Comment: @Mithril Are you importing celery in other modules ? Do you have this `absolute_import` statement in these modules ?